# Alt-R broken in Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse

For some reason "Alt-R" no longer opens the "Run" menu in Eclipse Indigo. All the other Alt- combinations work to open the other menus, but not Alt-R. Also, this combo doesn't seem to be bound to any other command. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was not eclipse, but the sysdeo Tomcat plugin. Remove the plugin, and Alt-R magically starts working.

The fix was to go into the keybindings and remove both of the tomcat key bindings - "Tomcat Quick Restart" and "Tomcat start/stop". The strange thing is, these were supposedly bound to CTRL-T and CTRL-SHIFT-T. So I don't know why they were interfering with CTRL-R.